# Postman able to use GET request properly but my program cannot

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests, postman

I have a GET and PUT request built below:

```
    from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

userStorage =[
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "currentBot": "BestBot"
    }
]

class User(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        for user in userStorage:
            if(id == user["id"]):
                return user, 200
        return "User not found", 404

    def put(self, id):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("currentBot")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        for user in userStorage:
            if(id == user["id"]):
                user["currentBot"] = args["currentBot"]
                return user, 200

        user = {
            "id": id,
            "currentBot": args["currentBot"]
        }
        userStorage.append(user)
        return user, 201

    def delete(self, id):
        global userStorage
        userStorage = [user for user in userStorage if user["id"] != id]
        return "{} is deleted.".format(id), 200

api.add_resource(User, "/user/<string:id>")

app.run(debug = True, port = 4000)
```

Postman can properly get a response 200 when I do a simple get request but when I try to do a request through my own program it returns a 404

```
import requests

payload2Storage = {
    "currentBot": "BestBot"
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}


params = {
    "id": "1234"
}


#response = requests.request("PUT", "http://127.0.0.1:4000/user/", data=payload2Storage, params=params, headers=headers)

response2 = requests.request("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:4000/user/", params=params, headers=headers)
```

Is there something wrong with my request to get the info from userStorage?

Answer (score 1):

In the client code, changing from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` worked for me. Try this:

```
response2 = requests.request("GET", "http://localhost:4000/user/", params=params, headers=headers)
```

OR in the server code, bind the server to 127.0.0.1 explicitly via host argument like this:

```
app.run(debug = True, port = 4000, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Other error in the code is user["id"] returns a str while id is a int, change the code as below:

```
def get(self, id):
    for user in userStorage:
        if(id == int(user["id"])):
            return user, 200
    return "User not found", 404
```

Comment: It still returns a 404. I noticed in the URL its creating a query string request so the url looks like this:  /user/?id=1234 HTTP/1.1" 404 -. I noticed that if I just plugged in the id directly into the url without the "?id=" it actually works. Would this be the line that causes this? api.add_resource(User, "/user/<string:id>")     (in original server code snippet)

Comment: do this change `api.add_resource(User, "/user/<int:id>")`

Comment: Still returning a 404?  '127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2018 11:57:40] "GET /user/?id=1234 HTTP/1.1" 404 -'

Comment: there is a discrepency here: In your server program you are expecting id as a Path Param i.e. `api.add_resource(User, "/user/<int:id>")` whereas from your request you are sending it as a Query Param and hence 404. Change your client to have this `response2 = requests.request("GET", "http://localhost:4000/user/1234", params=params, headers=headers)`

Comment: I see where you are coming from. however the id is the param. how do I tell it to put the id as a query param as the id is flexible and can change depending on the user being searched?

Comment: You should consider using flask instead of flask-restful that provides you with much flexiblity in dealing with query and path parameters OOB. flask-restful documentation is little sketchy about dealing with the query parameters.